# How to define a function and pass training and test datasets in Scala?

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I want to define a function in Scala in which I can pass my training and test datasets and then it perform a simple machine learning algorithm and returns some statistics. How should do that? What will be the parameters data type?

Imagine, you need to define a function which by taking training and test datasets performs a simple classification algorithm and then return the accuracy.

What I expect to have is like as follow:

```
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, datadir + "/example.txt");
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 11L);
val training = splits(0).cache();
val test = splits(1);

val results1 = SVMFunction(training, test)
val results2 = RegressionFunction(training, test)
val results3 = ClassificationFunction(training, test)
```

I need just the declaration of the functions and not the code that produce the results1, results2, and results3.

```
def SVMFunction ("I need help here"){
//I know how to work with the training and test datasets to generate the results.
//So no need to discuss what should be here
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why just someone vote it down? It's a serious question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I imagine it was because it's  ill defined (and sounds very like you're trying to get an answer for an assignment). Particularly "what will be the parameters data type?" How can we answer that from the information you've given in the question. Your question doesn't show any evidence you've tried anything or done any research into how.

Comment: @Mohammad have you seen [mllib page on classification algorithms](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html)? If no -- take a look, if yes, what wasn't clear?

Comment: It's not an assignment. I have done lots of research on the web but I could not find any answer. I saw the mllib documentation. But as I want to test several algorithms on the same training and test datasets, I need to write a function for each algorithm and then pass the training and test datasets to the function. I ask about the data type because I don't know what should I give the function parameters types. So please help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using supervised learning you should opt for [LabeledPoint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint). Excerpt from mllib doc:

> A labeled point is a local vector, either dense or sparse, associated with a label/response. In MLlib, labeled points are used in supervised learning algorithms. We use a double to store a label, so we can use labeled points in both regression and classification. For binary classification, a label should be either 0 (negative) or 1 (positive). For multiclass classification, labels should be class indices starting from zero: 0, 1, 2, ....

And example is:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

// Create a labeled point with a positive label and a dense feature vector.
val pos = LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0, 3.0))

// Create a labeled point with a negative label and a sparse feature vector.
val neg = LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.sparse(3, Array(0, 2), Array(1.0, 3.0)))
```

Comment: I can not understand relation of your answer to my question! I need a way to pass a dataset to a function. Is this really related to what I said?